# Неправильно срабатывает последний if

Tags: php

В моем случае в if должен срабатывать только если длинна $word>=8. Но почему-то срабатывает всегда

```
if($result_arr['user_mail'] === $new_user_mail)
        {
            $_POST['log'] = 'reg';
        }
        if($result_arr_for_login['user_login'] === $new_user_login)
        {
            $_POST['log'] = 'reg';
        }
        $pass_lenght=mb_strlen($new_user_pass, 'utf-8');
        if($pass_lenght<8)
        {
            $_POST['log'] = 'reg';              
        }
        if(($result_arr['user_mail']!=$new_user_mail)&&($result_arr_for_login['user_login'] != $new_user_login)&&(mb_strlen($new_user_pass,'utf-8')>7))
        {
            $reg_query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES( NULL, '".$new_user_mail."' , '".$new_user_login."' ,'".$new_user_pass."','".$new_user_date."','user','active')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $reg_query);
        }
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Dk8To

Comment: Конкретно этот участок кода правильный, может, у вас что-то ещё не так вызывается в окружающем коде?

Comment: Возможно. Там ещё три if , просто хотел упростить код, так как думал , что mb_strlen неправильно работает. Я выложил полный код в вопросе, некорректно работает последний if.
Он почему-то игнорирует 
```
(mb_strlen($new_user_pass,'utf-8')>7)
```

Comment: что-то меня гложет сомнение, а там не должно быть вместо $new_user_pass что-нибудь типа $result_arr['user_password'] ?

Answer (score 0):

`if($pass_lenght<8)` или `if($pass_lenght=<8)`
Знак `=` не забыли?

Comment: Проблема в том , что если $pass_lenght < 8, if срабатывает